# count click on pop up registred in phpmyadmin

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, counter

I have a problem. The IP doesn't appears in the other table (in the same db).

**In the page "recette1.php?id=1"**

```
<?php
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=recettes', 'root', 'root');

include("C:/wamp64/www/doc/ip_visiteurs.php");


$req = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE cuisine SET visiteurs = visiteurs + 1');
$req->execute();
$req->closeCursor();

$req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT id_recette, visiteurs FROM cuisine');
$req->execute();
$data = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$req->closeCursor();
?>
<?php echo $data->visiteurs;?> personnes ont vu cette recette.
```

**ip_visiteurs.php**

```
<?php

$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=recettes', 'root', 'root');


$ip_user = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

$ins = $bdd->query('INSERT INTO info_visiteurs(ip) VALUES(\'' . $ip_user .'\') WHERE id_recette="1"');




?>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to update only a specific record? Well by using a WHERE clause.

Comment: i'm really so stupid thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a database connection to do it the way you are wanting to.
I assume you have set up a database in phpmyadmin to write the data to.

In the (new?) PHP file which will record the data `onclick` you should include the following:

```
<?php
        $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=recettes', 'root', 'root');
        $req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT id_recette, visiteurs FROM cuisine');
        $req->execute();
        $data = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $req->closeCursor();    
?>

    <a href="javascript:void();" onclick="javascript:open_infos_1()"><div class="item">
        <div id="chateauchoco2" class="opac">

        <img src="../Dalila/chateauchoco2.png" onclick="document.getElementById('overlay3').style.display='block'" width="280" height="321"/>

        </div>
        </div>
        </a>

        <?php echo ($visiteurs);?> personnes ont vu cette recette.
        <script type="text/javascript">

        function open_infos_1()
        {
        window.open('recette1.php?id=1','recette1','menubar=no, scrollbars=no, top=50, left=100, width=800, height=600');
        }
        </script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=recettes', 'root', 'root');

$req = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE cuisine SET visiteurs = visiteurs + 1');
$req->execute();
$req->closeCursor();
?>
```

Comment: Hi thanks for you reply! I put this code on my page where I want to read the result. But the result is always 0. I don't undersand.. It's because this code down is in an other page than the code I gave you at the beginning?

Comment: `<?php
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=recettes', '***', '***');

$req = $bdd->prepare('UPDATE cuisine SET clicktimesrecette1 = clicktimesrecette1 + 1');
$req->execute();
$req->closeCursor();

$req = $bdd->prepare('SELECT id_recette, titre_recette, contenu_recette, lien_recette, visiteurs FROM cuisine');
$req->execute();
$data = $req->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$req->closeCursor();
?>
<?php echo $data->visiteurs;?> personnes ont vu cette recette.`

Comment: You need to have the code which increments the counter on a page which opens each time the click occurs, 
On a separate page you may have the display of the counter.

They don't need to be on the same page as the database is independent of both.

Comment: I edit the post at the beginning if you want to see

Comment: See revised answer